# Set Background of Adobe Flash Layer to Transparent

Tags: layers, transparency, background, adobe-flash

Is there a way to make a layer's background transparent?

I have a background image that is a little smaller than the frame size, so there is a white line when I export the movie from the layer on top of the background.

Is there a way I could set this white background to transparent so all the user sees is my background layer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ### Using the Publish Settings in Flash Professional
>
> The HTML for a SWF file can be created using the Publish Settings
>   feature in Flash. The Publish Settings dialog box provides an option
>   to affect the WMODE setting. The options selected in the Publish
>   Settings are added to the HTML source code automatically.
>
> 1. Choose <kbd>File > Publish Settings</kbd>. Make sure that HTML is selected.
> 2. Select `HTML`.
> 3. Choose `Transparent Windowless` from the Window Mode menu
>      to make the SWF file's background disappear in browsers that support
>      this feature.
> 4. Publish the document.

[Help Source](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/transparent-background-swf-file.html)

Comment: Is publishing the only way to set my transparency options?

Comment: @TylerDeWitt -  The layer should already be transparent unless you have an image in the background. Perhaps post an image if I am not understanding you correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced this. I am not a Flash expert but what I do is make my comp/canvass the same size as that layer <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> then change the sizes.